# How to define the scopes for network drives in windows indexing service?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, indexing-service

I'm stuck on a problem here with Indexing Service 
I send query's against the Indexing Service from an ASP.NET Application which works fine as long as I search on a whole Catalog.

```
SELECT ... FROM  testCat..Scope('Deep traversal of "\"')
```

But if I try to search in a specific folder I get no results at all.

```
SELECT ... FROM  testCat..Scope('Deep traversal of "\abc"')
```

Or

```
SELECT ... FROM  testCat..Scope('Deep traversal of "U:\MyIndexFolder\abc"')
```

The folder MyIndexfolder is the root of the Catalog and the sub directory "abc" exits. Does anyone has an idea what could be the cause of my problem?

P.S. I know that Indexing Service is deprecated but I have to work with it anyway so I hope there is someone out there who can help since it is hard to find useful information on the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of my problem was that my indexed folder is stored on a network drive.
And it seems that in this case it is not possible to use relative paths for the scope. You have to use the full network-path.

```
//servername/path
```

I hope this can help anyone else!